# hints and stepping stone on how to tackle this

Tags: python

Consider a dictionary that has strings as keys and integers as values - e.g. 
{'a':24, 'e':30, 't':12, 'n':10}

Write a function big_keys that takes such a dictionary as the first argument and an integer as the second argument and returns the list of keys all of whose values are bigger than the second argument. You must use a for loop to iterate over the dictionary.

I understand that i have to create a function but i do not understand "dictionary as the first argument and an integer as the second argument and returns the list of keys all of whose values are bigger than the second argumenT."

I have no working to show but all i have is

```
def big_keys:
    for keys in big_keys:
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! There are plenty of tutorials for Python if you just google it! :)

Comment: I have tried googling and it didn't go well :)

Comment: A googling of Python tutorial should take you to the Python.org tutorial where I guarantee you that you'll find what you're looking for. I'll even throw in the url free of charge, [Python.org tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: Cheers! have a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach for this kind of task is to create an empty list, iterate over all the values of the dictionary and check the condition. If the value meets the condition, append the corresponding key to the list. For example:

```
a = {'a':24, 'e':30, 't':12, 'n':10}
x = 11

def big_keys(dictionary, value):
  big_keys_list = []
  for k, v in dictionary.iteritems(): #iterating the dict items
    if v > value: # checking the condition
      big_keys_list.append(k) #append to list if meets the rule
  return big_keys_list

print big_keys(a, x) # ['a', 'e', 't']
```

Some further reading about [iteritems()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) and [list.append()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).
As a side-note, this can be also done using a more advanced technique called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in less lines:

```
def big_keys(dictionary, value):
  return [k for k, v in dictionary.iteritems() if v > value]
```

Comment: @Noop You are welcome. I hope you will also try to understand what's happening there and check the links I provided :)

Answer (score 0):

A function in python looks like this:

```
def big_keys(argument1,argument2):
    mylist = []
    # do some stuff
    return mylist
```

so if you have a dictionary name d

```
d = {'a':24, 'e':30, 't':12, 'n':10}
```

and a "cut off" value of 10 you would call the function like this

```
big_keys(d,10)
```

However I will the implementation of the function to you.